# Error en mensaje SuccessMessageMixin Django

Tags: django

estoy creando una vista basada en Clases con django dentro de la misma existe la opción de mensajes es aqui donde contiene error al grabar los datos me genera:

```
UnicodeDecodeError at /clientes/administrar_clientes

'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 23: ordinal not in range(128)
```

El código que uso es:

```
class CrearCliente(SuccessMessageMixin, CreateView):

    model = Cliente
    form_class = ClienteForm
    template_name = "administrador/crear_cliente.html"
    success_url = reverse_lazy("clientes:administrar_clientes")
    success_message = "%(nombres)s creado con éxito."
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
            context = super(CrearCliente, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
            codigo_definida = settings.CODIGO_INICIAL_AUTOMATICO
            try:
                cliente = Cliente.objects.all().latest('id')
                codigo_existente = int(cliente.codigo)
                codigo_nuevo = codigo_existente + 1
            except Cliente.DoesNotExist:
                codigo_nuevo = codigo_definida
            context['secuencia'] = str(codigo_nuevo).zfill(7)
            return context
```

Según noto el error se debe a que dentro del mensaje posee una tilde y esto provoca el error, tambien dentro de **views.py** he agregado la codificacion utf:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

como puedo corregir dicho error trate lo siguiente:

```
success_message = unicode("%(nombres)s creado con éxito.")
```

Pero tengo el mismo error, gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esto es más un error de Python que de Django. Tienes que decodificar el texto:

```
>>> print unicode('éxito') 
Traceback (most recent call last):   
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module> 
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Usa `decode` para esto:

```
>>> print unicode('éxito'.decode('utf-8')) 
éxito
```

Por lo tanto, en tu código puedes probar cambiando esta línea:

```
success_message = "%(nombres)s creado con éxito.".decode("utf-8")
```

Comment: Genial me ha servido de mucho gracias..!!